# Responsive Images for smartphone and tablet on landscape mode

Tags: css, wordpress, image, optimization, landscape

I got a very plain photo gallery site. Every page only contains a image (600 x 400) or a image slider. I have problem with the look of my website on smartphone/tablet on landscape mode or even a laptop. Because the bottom of the image/slider will just be chopped off. So you need to scroll down to see the whole image. On my desktop or portait mode on small devices it looks good. I had like the image/slider be showing in a smaller size on those screens so you dont need to scroll down to see the whole image. Can someone help me with this? I built this with a twenty sixteen childtheme in wordpress.

Thanks,
Hazy

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Slick carousel. that's an easy slider initiator and will save you lots of time and adjustments: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

For single images use the following css properties :

```
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
```

Comment: This is my first website so Im quite new into this. But how do I target the specific page with the sinlge image ? Also do I need a media query ?

Comment: on the page, wrap everything in some `<div class="my-container">...</div>`. than, you can declare your statement inside: `.my-container img { ... }`. you can also give your `img` a class and work with it directly.